# How to convert set_stamp column of v$backup_set to normal time?

Tags: oracle

When querying v$backup_set,I got a set_stamp column value like '938983113'. How can I convert it to normal time, such as YYYYMMDD HH24:mi:ss format.

Comment: Why do you think it is a timestamp? It is just a unique number for the backup.  See docs - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_1043.htm#REFRN30025

Comment: Accrording to 'Backup and Recovery User's Guide 11g Release 2 (11.2)',it said that '`the most common substitution variable is %U,
which generates a unique name. Others include %d for the DB_NAME, %t for the backup set time stamp, %s for the backup set number, and %p for the backup piece number`'.When using `backup as backupset database format 'd:\backup\full_%d_%s_%p_%t.bkp'',i found the %t equal to set_stamp column of v$backup_set.